# ¿Por qué sale None al hacer sort en una lista?

Tags: python, metodos

Tengo un problema al usar el método `sort` en una lista.

```py
lista = ["Carlos", "Esau", "Jose", "Maria"]
lista_ordenada = lista.sort()

print(lista_ordenada)
```

Al ejecutar me devuelve `None` en `lista_ordenada`, lo cual me parece curioso porque encontré otra forma que me parece más larga, se las muestro a continuación:

```
lista = ["Carlos", "Esau", "Jose", "Maria"]
variable_lista = lista
lista_ordenada = variable_lista.sort()

print(variable_lista)
```

Como pueden ver, me parece redundante, no entiendo porqué no me funciona en el primer código y sí en el segundo.
¿Alguien podría explicarme por qué no se puede de la primer manera?

Comment: `obj.sort()` es un método del propio objeto secuenciable (la lista en este caso) y no retorna nada porque es "destructivo" con el contenido de la secuencia, ya que una vez lo ejecutas este cambia. Por otro lado, Python tiene una **función** llamada [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), la cual si devuelve una lista ordenada de cualquier secuencia iterable, dejando la original intacta.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, casi no entiendo pero me detendré a analizarlo mas detenidamente

Answer (score 2):

El método [sort](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) de una lista en Python, ordena la lista y devuelve None.
Por lo cual al almacenar el resultado del método en una variable y luego mandarla al print, estas imprimiendo el resultado devuelto por el método.

Este sería un ejemplo de como deberías ejecutar tu código para ordenar la lista:

```py
lista = ["Esau","Carlos", "Maria", "Jose"]
# imprime la lista desornada
print(lista)
# ordena la lista
lista.sort()
# imprime la lista ordenada
print(lista)
```

Y si no deseas modificar la lista original, entonces haces una copia y luego llamas al método sort de la copia de la lista.
Así:

```py
lista = ["Esau","Carlos", "Maria", "Jose"]
# imprime la lista deshornada
print(lista)
# copia la lista
lista_copia = lista.copy()
# ordena la lista
lista_copia.sort()
# imprime la lista ordenada
print(lista_copia)
```

Comment: Buena respuesta! Solo quería agregar que no es necesario guardar el resultado de lista.sort() en una variable.

Comment: Si, se me escapo cuando copie el código, gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: Vi tu nueva edición. "lista_copia = lista" no copia la lista, si no que le da otro nombre a la misma. Por lo que en el fondo, el segundo código hace lo mismo que el primero. Por cierto, podés usar la función sorted, que devuelve una nueva lista ordenada. Y de nada :D

Comment: @DanteS. también lo hice de esa forma, sin guardar el sort() en una variable y es menos engorroso, pero guardé en una variable porque así aprendi con una app para aprender python. En fin, gracias por la ayuda a ambos.

Comment: @Dante S. Corregido! nuevamente gracias.